# Appceleartor - prevent Android keyboard from appearing when clicking on a TableView row

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am in the process of building an app with Appcelerator Alloy and cannot figure out how to prevent the Android keyboard from appearing when I click on a TableView row - or perhaps when the resulting `$.myWindow.open()` event fires.

Here is my Alloy XML:

```
<Alloy>
<TabGroup title="Testing">
    <Tab title="News">
        <Window id="newsWindow" class="container" title="News">
            <TableView id="tableView"/>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
    <Tab title="Photos">
        <Window class="container" title="Photos">
            <Label>Testing</Label>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
</TabGroup>
```

Here is the XML of the row that is injected into the TableView:

```
<Alloy>
<TableViewRow id="rowView">
    <ImageView id="image"/>
    <View id="postView" layout="vertical">
        <Label id="articleLabel"/>
        <Label id="articleDetails"/>
    </View>
</TableViewRow>
```

and here is the code that fires when the Row is clicked.

```
$.tableView.addEventListener('click',function(e){
var postView = Alloy.createController('postView', e.row.args).getView();
if (OS_IOS)
{ $.navGroupWin.openWindow(postView); }
if (OS_ANDROID)
{
    postView.open();
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for (in the api doc)

```
softKeyboardOnFocus : Number
Determines keyboard behavior when this view is focused.

One of Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEFAULT_ON_FOCUS, Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_HIDE_ON_FOCUS, or Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS.

Default: Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEFAULT_ON_FOCUS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> if(OS_Android)
>
> Ti.UI.Android.hideSoftKeyboard();